# NumberRangeFilter slider shows One or more participants failed to draw() error on seeking the bar from left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I've created a timeline viz using Google Charts and added a dashboard with a NumberRangeFilter to allow self to move around and even zoom in so as to see certain entries more clearly. It mostly throws a error "**One or more participants failed to draw()**" and **"Cannot read property 'v' of undefined"** when I slide it from left.

**Cannot read property 'v' of undefined** error comes only once when I try to slide the slider from left at very first time. However, I don't see any problem when I seek it from right.
I've looked up other responses for this type of error but couldn't find anything that worked.

**Can anyone recommend a fix?**

Sharing the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls', 'timeline']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

        function drawVisualization() {
            var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard'));

            var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
                'containerId': 'control',
                'ui': {'labelStacking': 'vertical'},
                'options': {
                    'filterColumnLabel': 'Start',
                    'hAxis':{'slantedText':'true','direction':'1','format': { 'pattern':'0' }},
                    'hAxis.gridlines.color':'#ccc',
                    'hAxis': {
                        gridlines: {
                            color: 'transparent'
                        }
                    }
                },
            });

            var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                'chartType': 'Timeline',
                'containerId': 'chart',
                'options': {
                    'width': 1300,
                    'height': 600,
                    'labelStacking': 'horizontal', 'format': { 'pattern':'####','fractionDigits':'0','groupingSymbol':'','showRangeValues':true },
                    'chartArea': {
                        width: '100%', // make sure this is the same for the chart and control so the axes align right
                        height: '100%'
                    },
                    'backgroundColor': '#ffd',
                    //'minValue': 0, 
                },
                'view': {
                        'columns': [0, 1, 2, 3]
                },
            });

            var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Processor', 'Task', 'Start', 'End'],
                [ 'XXX1', 'Func1', 0, 10 ],
                [ 'XXX1', 'Func3', 12, 15 ],
                [ 'XXX2', 'Func2', 5, 12 ],
                [ 'XXX1', 'Func1', 35, 60 ],
                [ 'XXX1', 'Func1', 65, 90 ],
                [ 'XXX1', 'Func1', 95, 190 ],
                [ 'XXX1', 'Func2', 18, 19 ],
                [ 'XXX3', 'Func2', 5, 9 ],
                [ 'XXX3', 'Func4', 18, 20 ],
                [ 'XXX3', 'Func3', 10, 15 ],
                [ 'XXX5', 'Func3', 10, 15 ],
                [ 'XXX4', 'Func3', 10, 15 ],
                [ 'XXX2', 'Func3', 10, 15 ],
                [ 'XXX7', 'Func3', 10, 15 ],
            ]);

            dashboard.bind(control, chart);
            dashboard.draw(data);
        }

    </script>
</head>

<style>
    .center {
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid green;
    }
</style>
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="dashboard" style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow:scroll;">
        <div class="center" id="control" style="margin-right: auto; border: 1px solid green;"> </div > <br>
        <div id="chart" style="position: relative; width: 600px; height: 200px; bottom: 0px; padding-bottom: 200px; "></div>
    </div>
    <div id="junk_div" style="display: none;"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using `'number'` columns for `'Start'` and `'End'`,
the number value represents *milliseconds*

the data from the question includes really small ranges of time
and the chart has trouble drawing the ranges,
specifically when the row containing `0` is removed
which is also the result when the range is *slid from the left*

to test, remove the first row of data and draw the chart,
it will result in the same error, without using the slider

there are a couple things that will prevent the chart from throwing an error

1) increase the time ranges represented to seconds, e.g.

```
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Processor', 'Task', 'Start', 'End'],
  [ 'XXX1', 'Func1', 0, 1000 ],
  [ 'XXX1', 'Func1', 3500, 6000 ],
  [ 'XXX1', 'Func1', 6500, 9000 ],
  ...
```

2) use the `hAxis.mimValue` option to force the chart to start from zero,
regardless of the rows in the data

```
hAxis: {
  minValue: 0,
}
```

this option is used in the following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages:['controls', 'table', 'timeline']
});

function drawVisualization() {
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard')
  );

  var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'control',
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'Start',
      ui: {
        format: {
          pattern: '0'
        },
        labelStacking: 'vertical'
      }
    }
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Timeline',
    containerId: 'chart',
    options: {
      backgroundColor: '#ffd',
      height: 336,
      hAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
      }
    }
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'table'
  });

  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Processor', 'Task', 'Start', 'End'],
    [ 'XXX1', 'Func1', 0, 10 ],
    [ 'XXX1', 'Func1', 35, 60 ],
    [ 'XXX1', 'Func1', 65, 90 ],
    [ 'XXX1', 'Func1', 95, 190 ],
    [ 'XXX1', 'Func2', 18, 19 ],
    [ 'XXX1', 'Func3', 12, 15 ],
    [ 'XXX2', 'Func2', 5, 12 ],
    [ 'XXX2', 'Func3', 10, 15 ],
    [ 'XXX3', 'Func2', 5, 9 ],
    [ 'XXX3', 'Func3', 10, 15 ],
    [ 'XXX3', 'Func4', 18, 20 ],
    [ 'XXX4', 'Func3', 10, 15 ],
    [ 'XXX5', 'Func3', 10, 15 ],
    [ 'XXX7', 'Func3', 10, 15 ],
  ]);

  dashboard.bind(control, [chart, table]);
  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
  <div id="control"></div>
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <div id="table"></div>
</div>
```

**other notes...**

1) recommend **not using** `jsapi` to load the library

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the jsapi loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

this will *only* change the `load` statement

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages:['controls', 'table', 'timeline']
});
```

2) there are several *invalid* options on both the `chart` and `control`

`control`: `'ui'` should be part of `'options'`, no option for `'hAxis'` exists
(and if it did, it should only be defined once)

`chart`: there are no options for 'labelStacking' or 'format'

3) recommend **not using** `style` attributes on the containers

in addition, the size settings in the `style` attribute conflict with the size settings in the chart `options`

`<div id="chart" style="position: relative; width: 600px; height: 200px; bottom: 0px; padding-bottom: 200px; "></div>`

Comment: Thanks a lot @WhiteHat